# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent distant relationship with many to many models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have three models and many-to-many relationships. Environments have many Services. Services have many ServiceRoles.  I would like to return the applicable ServiceRoles of a given Environment, but I am unsure of what I may need to define in the Environment model.

In my Controller I have:

```
public function getServiceRoles($id)
{  
    $environment = Environment::find($id);
    $serviceRoles = $environment->serviceRoles;
}
```

My MySQL tables and fields are as follows:

```
environments [id | name]  
services [id | name]  
service_roles [id | name]  
environment_service [id | environment_id | service_id]  
service_service_roles [id | service_id | service_role_id]
```

Environment Model

```
class Environment extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

Service Model

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function environments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Environment');
    }

    public function serviceRoles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ServiceRole');
    }
}
```

ServiceRole Model

```
class ServiceRole extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship to query for models through an intermediary model.

```
class Environment extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
    }

    public function serviceRoles()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ServiceRoles', 'App\Service');
    }
}
```

You should be able to query the an environment model for all of it's service roles.

```
$environment = Environment::with('serviceRoles')->first();

// Should output a collection of ServiceRole models
dd($environment->serviceRoles);
```